# Grails 4 App stalls during start up on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: tomcat, grails, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Grails 4.0.1 application that run fine locally.  I can run the WAR file using `java -jar...`, but the I try to deploy it to AWS Elastic Beanstalk running Java 8 and Tomcat 8, and it just stalls during start up without any error message at all.

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=64m; support was removed in 8.0
29-Jan-2020 11:49:38.574 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/8.5.50
29-Jan-2020 11:49:38.634 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Jan 6 2020 22:09:40 UTC
29-Jan-2020 11:49:38.634 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version number: 8.5.50.0
29-Jan-2020 11:49:38.634 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
29-Jan-2020 11:49:38.634 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            4.14.158-101.185.amzn1.x86_64
29-Jan-2020 11:49:38.634 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
29-Jan-2020 11:49:38.634 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.232.b09-0.48.amzn1.x86_64/jre
29-Jan-2020 11:49:38.634 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_232-b09
29-Jan-2020 11:49:38.634 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
29-Jan-2020 11:49:38.634 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /usr/share/tomcat8
29-Jan-2020 11:49:38.634 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /usr/share/tomcat8
29-Jan-2020 11:49:38.635 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib]
29-Jan-2020 11:49:39.218 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
29-Jan-2020 11:49:39.309 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
29-Jan-2020 11:49:39.328 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
29-Jan-2020 11:49:39.330 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
29-Jan-2020 11:49:39.331 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 2803 ms
29-Jan-2020 11:49:39.447 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
29-Jan-2020 11:49:39.448 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.50
29-Jan-2020 11:49:39.479 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT]
29-Jan-2020 11:49:44.838 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXml.setVersion Unknown version string [4.0]. Default version will be used.
2020-01-29 11:50:03.589  INFO --- [ost-startStop-1] us.cloudcard.api.ApplicationLoader       : The following profiles are active: production

Configuring Spring Security Core ...
... finished configuring Spring Security Core


Configuring Spring Security REST 3.0.0.RC1...
... finished configuring Spring Security REST

    ... with GORM support
29-Jan-2020 11:50:09.141 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.checkPoolConfiguration maxActive is smaller than 1, setting maxActive to: 100
2020-01-29 11:50:13.580  WARN --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.GenericTypeAwarePropertyDescriptor : Invalid JavaBean property 'exceptionMappings' being accessed! Ambiguous write methods found next to actually used [public void grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.AjaxAwareAuthenticationFailureHandler.setExceptionMappings(java.util.List)]: [public void org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ExceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler.setExceptionMappings(java.util.Map)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I was missing two things:

1. I needed to mark the Spring Boot Starter Tomcat artifact as provided, so it wouldn't conflict with the external Tomcat container.

```
dependencies {
    ...
    provided "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    ...
}
```

2. I also needed to increase the size of my container. I was trying to run on a t3.nano, and I bumped up to a t3.micro.